# possible? radius server with active directory users and google authentication

Tags: freeradius, google-authenticator

We currently have an old RSA token - Radius environment we want to replace

Would this architecture be possible?

(this works, there are examples on the internet)
Linux server
Google Authentication
Fee radius server

Now the new part:
User list would get pulled from active directory, on the linux server the google authenticatior token would be (manually generated)

Or should we just create the users with the same name manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible with [totpcgi and freeradius](https://github.com/mricon/totp-cgi/tree/master/contrib/freeradius), though we've not done it against AD but FreeIPA. We use this setup on our Cisco VPN appliances and users authenticate with their username and password+token (i.e. the same behaviour as RSA tokens).

I'd love to have more input on how well it works for others, especially if someone can provide documentation on how to drop-replace RSA infrastructure with totpcgi in a heterogeneous Linux-Windows environment. :) Our primary goal thus far has been implementing it for Linux servers.

Comment: Not to dig up an old post but why ask a new question when this is what I want to know as well.  We're trying to use totpcgi on top of freeradius connected with our AD.  Using the LDAP is all good except as per best practice our DC's are NOT CA's this leads to a problem in the config file.  Do you know if there are extra options available to setup on config or is it just expected that your LDAP server is also a CA?

Comment: @MoSiAc It's best if you ask this on https://github.com/mricon/totp-cgi/issues and we'll be glad to help you out.